# run jekyll --server failed in win7

Tags: jekyll, pygments

when i run jekyll --server,it built failed ,and display this :

> [2013-01-10 15:34:52] regeneration: 1 files changed
>   **Liquid Exception: Failed to get header. in 2013-01-05-vim.markdown**
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/popen.rb:357:
>   in `rescue in get_header'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/popen.rb:338:
>
>   in`get_header'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/popen.rb:235:
>   in `block in mentos'
>
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in`timeout'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/popen.rb:209:
>   ...

i use pygments to highlight my code..

help me !!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, @user1965893. Your question is not according to the standards outlined in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Maybe you should consider refrasing the question a little so it is an actual question.

Comment: Try downloading a portable version here http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2013/07/20/buildportablejekyll.html

Answer (score 5):

Check if your python version is 2.X. Python 3 is unsupported by the pygments.rb gem.

Answer (score 2):

This is giving me headache...: since 2011 it seems that "pygments.rb" is reported to work with Python 3 as per this Jekyll installation guide for windows mentioned in the official Jekyll installation docs "http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2011/09/01/runningjekyllwindows.html" (which just to blow in more confusion today got an expired domain...)

So yea, how do you install Jekyll, which by the way is described as a *Ruby* static website generator on its github page - when it:

1. requires Python while being a Ruby thing
2. recommends Python 3 leaving you alone to figure out that it only works with Python 2
3. doesn't say a thing about it after 2 years

Well you simply don't.