# Jekyll on Windows Liquid Exception: Failed to get header

Tags: ruby, windows, python-2.7, jekyll

I'm trying to use Jekyll on my windows 7 (64bit) PC.

I have installed Ruby, Ruby Devkit, Python 2.7, Jekyll and Pygments but getting this error

```
E:\jekyll\my-site>jekyll serve
Configuration file: E:/jekyll/my-site/_config.yml
            Source: E:/jekyll/my-site
       Destination: E:/jekyll/my-site/_site
      Generating...   Liquid Exception: Failed to get header. in 2013-07-19-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
error: Failed to get header.. Use --trace to view backtrace
```

Comment: I made it work on you configuration with the following specifications: Only Pigments 0.5.0 works (I had to uninstall 0.5.2 and install 0.5.0 first). Also, in my PATH I had a reference to Python 3.3 instead of Python 2.7 that I had to change back to 2.7. Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364028/jekyll-on-windows-pygments-not-working

Comment: Just add this line to your _config.yml:

`highlighter: rouge` it will works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also got this error, and a couple of other similar errors too, and finally got to a solution: you need to have a couple of compatible versions of the required Ruby, Python and Pygments.

- Install Ruby 1.9.3-p448 version (download [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/));
- Install Python 2.7.5 version (download [here](http://www.python.org/download/));
- Install Pygments 0.5.0

  `gem uninstall pygments.rb`
  `gem install pygments.rb --version "=0.5.0"`

I hope it helps.

Edited: Don't forget to add the correct PATHs to your system variables. In my case, it was:

> C:\Python27;C:\Ruby193

---

In order to improve this content, there is a simple tutorial (written in Portuguese, but I guess you can understand the steps, always considering the versions of software/plugins listed above) - [view tutorial](http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/blog/2013/01/18/como-instalar-o-jekyll-no-windows-7/).

Comment: Just add this line to your _config.yml:

`highlighter: rouge` it will works fine.

Comment: I had the same issue and adding `highlighter: rouge` to my `_config.yml` worked. Thanks @GopaThemes

Answer (score 4):

Another possible cause for this error message on Windows is that the path to the Pygments scripts contains spaces. Took me a while to figure this one out...

Answer (score 3):

For my situation, install pygments 0.5.0 or 0.5.4 both have problem. I fixed by re-install python 2.7.6. Please refer to following answer:
https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1181#issuecomment-35963876

Comment: Thank you. I'm used pygments 0.6.3 and have the same problem while downgrade python version.

Answer (score 0):

I had two versions of python installed on my system.(Windows 8.1)
Python22 and Python27.
I removed Python22, added Python27 to System variables and issue got fixed.