# Jekyll Quick-Start Doesn't Work

Tags: jekyll

I've tried to start a Jekyll blog locally according to the instructions at jekyllrb.com.

So once I type:

```
jekyll serve
```

Server should be running at localhost:4000 but there's nothing. A blank page.

Here's what I get back after the "jekyll serve" command:

```
Configuration file: C:/Users/Atte/newblog/_config.yml
        Source: C:/Users/Atte/newblog
   Destination: C:/Users/Atte/newblog/_site
  Generating... C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-s
pawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn.rb:162: warning: cannot close fd before spawn
←[31m  Liquid Exception: No such file or directory - /bin/sh in _posts/2013-12-1
4-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown←[0m
done.
Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000
Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

What could be the problem? I have (obviously) been unable to find the answer anywhere even though I've spent *so much* time on this.

Comment: According to the error message, Jekyll cannot find the 'welcome-to-jekyll.md'. Check if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with Pygments, you have two options: the simplest solution is disabling Pygments in `_config.yml`

```
pygments: false
```

You won't have syntax highligth but you can use a client side solution like [Prism](http://prismjs.com/). On the other hand, if you want to have Pygments, you can follow [@zzheng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17404260/915034) answer.

Comment: I thought I had done that already but apparently not... now it works like magic, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the _posts folder and delete the dummy post welcome-to-jekyll.markdown file.

mine at the current time is: **2014-10-19-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown**

Answer (score 0):

For latest version(2.3.0) use "***highlighter: null***" instead "***pygments: false***"